# Adobe Acrobat XI Pro and screen resolution

Tags: windows-7, adobe-acrobat

I recently upgraded from Acrobat 9 Pro to Acrobat XI Pro, running on Windows 7.  I keep my Display/Text size on "Larger" (150%) and it was never a problem with Acrobat 9 - the toolbars etc. were the same size as they were in other applications.  However, with XI, the toolbars and other top-of-screen items (except the menu bar) are HUGE, and screens such as customizing toolbars don't display down to the bottom (i.e., can't see the "OK" button).  I tried reducing my system text size preference to "Medium" and Acrobat looked fine that way, but all other applications are way too small for me to see.  Is there any internal hidden setting that I can use to take the toolbars etc. down in size, as I had with Acrobat 9 Pro?

Comment: I believe this is simple to explain.  The way Acrobat generates its interface was change which conflicts with your settings.  I suggest getting in tough with Adobe.

Answer (score 0):

While being in an important development product, I have not yet upgraded to the very newest version of Acrobat Pro, but there is now a setting where you can adjust the scaling. Most likely, it would be in the General or Display tab of the Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

In Acrobat: Edit/Preferences/General 'Scale for screen resolution (restart required) - default is 200% - amend to 100% - voila!